# Writing a formula to reindex a column with duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of values that has ID values listed like below where its ordered numerically, but has random high values interspersed.  They're interspersed because I have another column ordered alphabetically and I added names.

I want it to be transformed into the one on the right.  Where it goes from 1 -> N but retains the numbering if they're the same.

Is there an easy formula anyone can think of without using VBA.

```
BC1              BC1
BC123            BC2
BC3              BC3
BC4       ->     BC4
BC4              BC4
BC1441           BC5
BC5              BC6
BC5              BC6
BC1231           BC7
```

Comment: Do they always start with "BC" or at least two characters?

Comment: Put `BC1` in B1 then use this B2 and copy down `=IF(A1<>A2,"BC" & MID(B1,3,LEN(B1))+1,B1)`

Comment: Yes. I was having trouble figuring out how to get it to reindex if the numbers are the same. *Thanks Scott

Comment: @ScottCraner - Please update in Answer section.